# Python, Loop - Do statements until specific answer is given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently a noob learning Python, and I am trying to complete an exercise. The exercise requires me to:

1. Input an integer.
2. Depending on whether that integer is odd or even, do a specific calculation and print the answer.
3. Take the given answer, and repeat specific calculations again until answer is equal to 1.

The code I have so far completes the first 2 actions, but I am struggling to implement the loop which will continue to rerun the calculations until the answer is 1. Here is my code so far:

```
def collatz(getNumber):

    if getNumber % 2 == 0:
        print(getNumber // 2)
    elif getNumber % 2 == 1:
        print(3 * getNumber + 1)

print('Please write a number')
number = collatz(int(input()))
```

Comment: you need a `while` loop and a `break`. And to search this site a little harder as this question is asked several times a week.

Comment: You also need to `return` a value instead of printing it if you expect `number` to contain the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`while` loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop):

```
def collatz(number):
    print(number)
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number //= 2
        else:
            number = number * 3 + 1
        print(number)
```

Alternatively, you could use recursion:

```
def collatz(number):
    print(number)
    if number == 1:
        return
    collatz(number // 2 if number % 2 == 0 else number * 3 + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you; for some reason I had set it in my head that reoccurring blocks in the language were not allowed...

Answer (score 1):

```
def collatz(n):
    print n
    if n == 1:
        return
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n2 = (n / 2)
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        n2 = (3 * n + 1)

    collatz(n2)


print('Please write a number')
number = collatz(int(input()))
```